# Using Overflow inside Flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I am playing around with flex, but i run into a problem. I have my body and i use flex on it to span the howl height, so far no issue.

But i have in one of my div element a table that can become very big. I want to apply an overflow only on that div. but i dont succeed in it.

If you make the screen smaller, the scrollbar apears but on page level, i want it only to display on table level.

i do something wrong on the second level off flex i think:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
background-color: grey;
}
.workspace {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
    .begin {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .end {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        background-color: green;
        padding: 5px;
        align-self: flex-end;
        > button {
            height: 64px;
            width: 64px;
        }
    }
}
.beginBlock {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100%;
}
.result {
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Please check the following test:
http://jsfiddle.net/jansor/VWuCE/

Comment: Maybe this will help http://devbryce.com/site/flexbox/